# Select a marker method with Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have an app that sends a notification every time the user approaches to a map on `GMSMapView`.

I want that when the user opens the notification (`UILocalNotification`) the marker will be already selected and its info window will be visible.

I've searched for a method in the delegate that do that (selectAMarker:/selectAMarkerInPosition: or something like that) but I haven't found something like that.

Anyone knows a method that do that/know how can I do that?

Is it even possible?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you like this method

```
-(BOOL) mapView:(GMSMapView *) mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
NSLog(@"try");
return YES;
}
```

Dont Forget to call delegate

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GMSMapViewDelegate>
```

and

```
yourmapView_.delegate = self;
```